# How can I get a reference to a value from a Map<String, Object> if the other type is also an object?

Tags: java, serialization, reference, maps

If I am representing JSON string say as a Map<String, Object> object, how can I achieve the following?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args)  {
        Map<String, Object> properties = Map.of("k1", "v1", "k2", "v2");
        Map<String, Object> map = Map.of("id", 2819, "name", "John", "properties", properties);
        //map.get("properties").put("k3", "v3"); --> Doesn't work, since Object.put() doesn't exist
        Map<String, Object> propCopy = (Map<String, Object>) map.get("properties"); //Works but getting an unchecked cast error
    }
}
```

Comment: In your case, can you serialize the object as a string and store that string to a map, so you have a 1 to 1 map?

Comment: I can't since it is like a utility function which will be used multiple times.